# How can I get row by passing the slug to dependency injection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get the row by passing the slug using dependency injection, but the $variable returns me nothing.

**Controller Method**

```php
public function projectDetails(Project $project_name)
{
    dd($project_name);
}
```

**Model**

```php
namespace App\Modules\manufacturer\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name'];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('manufacturer-project-details/{project_name?}', 
    'ProjectController@projectDetails');
```

**Results**

```
Project {#1047 ▼
  #table: "projects"
  #fillable: array:1 [▼
    0 => "id"
  ]
  +timestamps: false
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #observables: []
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

However, when I `dd($project_details)`, a row should return containing the project name.

Answer (score 3):

laravel had magic method for it in model called as getRouteKeyName

just add this code on model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug'; //change this to desired column name
}
```

then you can use your controller without any change

here documentation for it [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: what is column name you want filter ? change the 'slug' into  your column name

Comment: @AbdullahFaraz just change the `return 'slug';` to `return 'name';` and it will work

Answer (score 2):

You can specify this in route declaration or in model method [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name):

```
// Route

Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', function (Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
```

OR

```
// Model

/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function projectDetails($project_name)
 {
    $data = Project :: where('project_name','=',$project_name)>get()->toArray();
    dd($data);
 }
```

Try This...I am not sure.. But i think.. you use method working in resource route

Comment: it worked but i is want to use dependency injection the way i posted the question

Answer (score 0):

same idea as @Ganesh but you better use first or fail

```
public function projectDetails($projectName)
{
    $project = Project::where('project_name', '=', $projectName)->firstOrFail();
    dd($project);
}
```

this way if the name is not available in tha DB, it will return a 404

but better add a method on the model to do the same

```
public function projectDetails($projectName)
{
    $project = Project::findOrFailByName($projectName);
    dd($project);
}
```

`Project.php`

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return Project 
 */
public static function findOrFailByName($name)
{
    return self::where('name', '=', $name)->firstOrFail();
}
```